# VBA code for search function for multiple slicers (in excel)

Tags: excel, vba, search, slicers

I have an excel file with over 15 pivot table and more than 10 slicers.

I'm looking for a VBA code to assignee to every slicer which could help me to have a "search" function for them. The current option in Excel would requires to create a pivot table behind each slicer which means that my excel file will crush.

Do you maybe have a "magical" VBA code which could help me to have a search function for every slicer in the excel file?

Many thanks in advance.

I'm no expert in VBA coding and therefore, I need help.